# JSSOR Full Width Slider images get artifacts when transitioning

Tags: transition, jssor

Been trying to get the slider to work as a banner of sorts. It is indeed working, mostly, but I keep bumping heads with this odd bug. The blue background takes the place of about half the image whenever it is moving, this can be due to a transition but also when you slide the image around slowly. See the picture below for more details.

[image: What is seen when the slider is transitioning]

The things I have done to the slider are simple, I've removed the share buttons, lowered both the arrows and the dots and finally I've added the two Icons seen above as circles on a white square. Please help!

Comment: Firefox 35.0 sending now.

Comment: Update: took a bit, had to Dropbox it as there were files not allowed by Gmail in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using another plugin. Others in my situation might want to try http://responsiveslides.com for another plugin.